# Matrix conditional formatting not working

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to simply conditionally format the font colour in a Power Bi Matrix visual column. I am using this rule setup:

[image]

I've hidden the field as this is confidential. It seems to force me to summarize the data field, not sure if this has anything to do with the issue?

This is part of the column once the conditional formatting has been put in place:

[image]

As you can see, the conditional formatting has not worked as expected. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the field in your matrix visual?  is it MIN([CONFIDENTALFIELD])?  Because that's the expression you're basing your formatting on.

Comment: Yeah it is set to Min on the matrix visual

Comment: the last data type is set to number instead of percent.  could that be an issue?  Are your values fractional amounts between 0 and 1?

Comment: No sorry that was just an error when creating the OP. I have set all 4 data types to percent on the condition statements but the original issue still persists. I don't understand why something so simple doesn't work!

Comment: I think it can be helpful when working with matrix formatting to copy the matrix, transform the copy to a table, and look at it there.  What we tend to think of as 'rows' and 'columns' in the matrix really are, from powerbi point of view, just one  column.  anyway, it might help to clear things up.  It's about all I can offer without understanding your model and measures better.